# slow down value changes for animation behaviour

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a program where I measure the current. But sometimes when the current is off, the values drop immediately from 12A to 0A. Since I use animated gauge this extreme case sometimes does not look so good.
So I would like to slow down the fall and when the value drops from 12A to 0A I would count down the value and animate that.

Do I use a for-loop for this or how to implement something like this?